# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, module

I've followed the cookiecutter instructions to create a django project using Docker. I'm trying to use pandas inside my project but whatever I do, I get:

```
(yt_venv) jan@Jans-MacBook-Pro summarizing % docker compose -f local.yml up                                                             
[+] Running 3/0
 ⠿ Container summarizing_local_postgres  Running                                                                                                     0.0s
 ⠿ Container summarizing_local_docs      Running                                                                                                     0.0s
 ⠿ Container summarizing_local_django    Created                                                                                                     0.0s
Attaching to summarizing_local_django, summarizing_local_docs, 
summarizing_local_postgres
summarizing_local_django    | PostgreSQL is available
summarizing_local_django    | Traceback (most recent call last):
summarizing_local_django    |   File "/app/manage.py", line 31, in <module>
summarizing_local_django    |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
summarizing_local_django    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
summarizing_local_django    |     utility.execute()
summarizing_local_django    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
summarizing_local_django    |     django.setup()
summarizing_local_django    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
summarizing_local_django    |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
summarizing_local_django    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
summarizing_local_django    |     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
summarizing_local_django    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
summarizing_local_django    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
summarizing_local_django    |     import_module(entry)
summarizing_local_django    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
summarizing_local_django    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
summarizing_local_django    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
summarizing_local_django    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
summarizing_local_django    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
summarizing_local_django    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
summarizing_local_django    | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
summarizing_local_django exited with code 1
```

In the same terminal and in the same venv:

```
(yt_venv) jan@Jans-MacBook-Pro summarizing % pip freeze | grep pandas
pandas==1.5.3
```

file where this happens:

```
import pandas as pd

from django.db import models
from summarizing.core.models import TimeStampedModel


class CallTranscript(TimeStampedModel):
...
```

Running pip install pandas says `Requirement already satisfied`

I've tried this with the current version of pandas as well. I have pandas in my INSTALLED_APPS. Very lost at the moment.

I've tried this with different version, and also with loading numpy instead of pandas. Same issue, so it does not seem to be a pandas problem, but more some configuration issue. I have done pip install pandas and also installed pandas via Pycharm. Pycharm shows pandas in the list of installed packages and as shown above, pip says it is already installed.

Comment: The error is in docker container, it has nothing to do with the host terminal.

Comment: My mistake. I had forgotten to build the containers again after adding the packages. Thanks for the hint